# ArrayAdapter not shown

Tags: android

My array adapter does not work.

MainActivityListFragment

```
    public class MainActivityListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[] values = new String[]{"hello","hi","nihao","hola","bye","bye bye","zaijian","hoo","haa"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);

    }
    }
```

content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.enxin.crystallise.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainActivityFrag"
    android:name="com.example.enxin.crystallise.MainActivityListFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

It does not display the string instead it shows a loading button
How do i get it to show?
others have used this code too but theirs can work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) **content_main.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_my"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
       android:id="@+id/mainActivityFrag"
       android:name="com.example.enxin.crystallise.MainActivityListFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

2) **MainActivityListFragment** :

```
    import android.app.ListFragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    public class MainActivityListFragment extends ListFragment {

      String [] values = new String[] { "hello","hi","nihao","hola","bye","bye bye","zaijian","hoo","haa" };

      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
         setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

      @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
         super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);

      }

}
```

Also you can read this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_fragment.htm

If it will help you (or not), let me know.